# How to prove periodicity of a trigonometric function

Tags: trigonometry, periodic-functions

> $f(x)= \sin(2x)+3\cos(8x)$
>
> Is the function periodic ?

What I did is equalize $f(x)=f(x+T)$ and after noting that $\sin(2x)=\sin(2T)=\sin(8x)=0$ and $\cos(2x)=\cos(2T)=\cos(8x)=1$ we get that both sides of the equation equal 3.

Is that enough to show that the function is periodic ?

Thanks.

Comment: No, GinKin, you haven't explained it in terms I can understand.

Comment: GinKin, you fail to actually _shift_ the function, which is the intended meaning behind $f(x+T)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

no need to be too complicated here:

both $sin \;x$ and $cos \;x$ are perodic, each with period $2\pi$

so $sin \; 2x$ is periodic, with period $\frac{2\pi}{2} = \pi$

and $cos \; 8x$ is periodic, with period $\frac{2\pi}{8} = \frac{\pi}4$

can you find the least common multiple of $\pi$ and $\frac{\pi}4$?

do you see why that must be the period of $\sin(2x)+3\cos(8x)$?

Comment: And the LCD is pi. I see. So the 3 before cosine doesn't affect the periodicity.

Comment: exactly. if you think of $3 cos 8x $ as a wave, then the $3$ is just the amplitude (size, intensity) of the wave. but the more fundamental thing, the periodicity, is determined by the argument of the cosine function. basically if you multiply $x$ by a constant $k$, then for a given rate of change of $x$ the bigger $k$ is the faster $kx$ moves through the fundamental cosine period of $2\pi$

Answer (score 6):

$$\begin{align}f(x+\pi)&=\sin(2(x+\pi))+3\cos(8(x+\pi))\\
&=\sin(2x+2\pi)+3\cos(8x+8\pi)\\
&=\sin(2x)\cos(2\pi)+\cos(2x)\sin(2\pi)+3\cos(8x)\cos(8\pi)-3\sin(8x)\sin(8\pi)\\
&=\sin(2x)+3\cos(8x)\\
&=f(x)\end{align}$$

Comment: Isn't that the same as what I did only with pi instead of T ?

Comment: In all honesty, I have no idea what you were trying to do in your question.  $T$ is a constant you are trying to find (in this case $\pi$) such that, if you were to shift the function by $T$, you would get the same function back.

Comment: I didn't realize that by asking if the function is periodic we need to find the period..

Comment: Well, at the very least you have to show a period exists, but in most contexts this involves finding the period.

Answer (score 1):

periodic says that for some $T$  ,given function repeats its value after $T$,or

$f(x)=f(x+T)$

now in your case  we know that $sin(x)=sin(x+2*\pi)$ and $cos(x)=cos(x+2*\pi)$

but for some  of periodic function,please read this

If the periods of two periodic functions do not have a common multiple, then their sum is not periodic. Perhaps the simplest example is $\sin(x) + \sin(\pi x),$ whose terms have least periods 2π and 2 respectively.

in your case  period of first function is   $2*\pi/2=\pi$ and  period of second function is $2*\pi/8=\pi/4$

can you continue?